# Use lazy loading as a animated effect with every scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm using lazy load jQuery script described in this website: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

What i want to achieve is that to have an fadeIn effect every time i scroll the webpage in both up and down directions but according to lazy loading default action is that it loads the image only one time after scrolling over the image and once images are loaded no fade-in effect occurs.
Is there any way by which we can have fad-In effect every time we scroll over the image in either direction?
I want to achieve animation similar to [this website](http://demonstration.easy-development.com/story-box/index.php) using lazy loading technique.

Here is my HTML and Script code:

```
<div class="img-col">

        <div class="banner">    
            <img src="lazyeffect.jpg" data-original="obanner1.jpg" class="lazy" width="400" height="194" alt="time of day">
        </div> 

        <div class="banner">    
            <img src="lazyeffect.jpg" data-original="obanner1.jpg" class="lazy" width="400" height="194" alt="time of day">
        </div> 

        <div class="banner">    
            <img src="lazyeffect.jpg" data-original="obanner1.jpg" class="lazy" width="400" height="194" alt="time of day">
        </div> 
    </div> 

      <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="lazyjs.js"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript">
            $("img.lazy").lazyload({
                effect: "fadeIn",
                event: "delay"
            });   

            $(window).bind("load", function(){
                var timeout= setTimeout(function(){
                    $("img.lazy").trigger("delay")
                }, 1000);

            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's a jQuery function. Hope this will work.

```
$( ".img-col" ).mouseenter(function() {
  put your code load over here.
});
```